# How to check if unity video ads ready to show or loaded

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins, sdk, ads, implementation

I'm using Unity Ads in my game. In older version i check if unity video ads are ready to show then call a method to show ads like this

```
public bool IsVideoReady()
    {
            if (Advertisement.IsReady())
                return true;
            else
                return false;
    }
```

But in new version i dont know how to check if unity video ads are ready or loaded to show.
My new script is

```
using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
    public class AdsInitializer : MonoBehaviour, IUnityAdsInitializationListener, IUnityAdsLoadListener, IUnityAdsShowListener
    {
        [SerializeField] string _androidGameId;
        [SerializeField] string _iOSGameId;
        string _gameId;
        [SerializeField] bool _testMode = true;
    
        private void Awake()
        {
            if (Advertisement.isInitialized)
            {
                Debug.Log("Advertisement is Initialized");
                LoadRewardedAd();
            }
            else
            {
                InitializeAds();
            }
        }
        public void InitializeAds()
        {
            _gameId = (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer) ? _iOSGameId : _androidGameId;
            Advertisement.Initialize(_gameId, _testMode, this);
        }
    
        public void OnInitializationComplete()
        {
            Debug.Log("Unity Ads initialization complete.");
            LoadInerstitialAd();
            LoadBannerAd();
        }
    
        public void OnInitializationFailed(UnityAdsInitializationError error, string message)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Unity Ads Initialization Failed: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        }
    
        public void LoadInerstitialAd()
        {
            Advertisement.Load("Interstitial_Android", this);
        }
    
        public void LoadRewardedAd()
        {
            Advertisement.Load("Rewarded_Android", this);
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsAdLoaded(string placementId)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsAdLoaded");
            Advertisement.Show(placementId,this);
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsFailedToLoad(string placementId, UnityAdsLoadError error, string message)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Error showing Ad Unit {placementId}: {error.ToString()} - {message}");
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsShowFailure(string placementId, UnityAdsShowError error, string message)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsShowFailure");
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsShowStart(string placementId)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsShowStart");
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            Advertisement.Banner.Hide();
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsShowClick(string placementId)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsShowClick");
        }
    
        public void OnUnityAdsShowComplete(string placementId, UnityAdsShowCompletionState showCompletionState)
        {
            Debug.Log("OnUnityAdsShowComplete "+showCompletionState);
            if (placementId.Equals("Rewarded_Android") && UnityAdsShowCompletionState.COMPLETED.Equals(showCompletionState))
            {
                Debug.Log("rewared Player");
            }
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            Advertisement.Banner.Show("Banner_Android");
        }
    
    
    
        public void LoadBannerAd()
        {
            Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
            Advertisement.Banner.Load("Banner_Android",
                new BannerLoadOptions
                {
                    loadCallback = OnBannerLoaded,
                    errorCallback = OnBannerError
                }
                );
        }
    
        void OnBannerLoaded()
        {
            Advertisement.Banner.Show("Banner_Android");
        }
    
        void OnBannerError(string message)
        {
    
        }
    
    }
```

i just want to know how to check if unity  interstital or rewarded ads are ready before showing them.
because in new versions Advertisment.isReady() is not working any more